# Urn with red and white balls problem

Tags: probability

In my textbook there is a question:

> An urn has $r$ red and $w$ white balls that are randomly removed one at a time. Let $R_i$ be the event that the $i$th ball removed is red. Find:
>   a) $P(R_i)$
>   b) $P(R_5|R_3)$
>   c) $P(R_3|R_5)$

I understand the solution for part a, but for parts b and c one of the steps is

[image: calculation]

I don't get how you can represent the probability of the third and fifth balls as a combination. Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Actually the "order" here does not matter much, as long as you have no information about other position. You may think that you have randomly permute all the balls and put them as a queue. Then you are asking the probability of a certain position is red given other position is red. You should see that how you labeled the position of the queue does not matter.